# Accessing and comparing data in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

With one dataframe, and for each entry, I want to find the number of times the row data `"new_page"` and `"treatment"` don't match.

Can someone also explain to me how to add an image? 
https://ibb.co/gSv7FR4

I would imagine it's something like this where if the condition meet, count goes up. I would appreciate an explanation of how to do this in addition to the solution of the above problem.

```py
if df.group[n]=='treatment' and df.landing_page[n]=='new_page'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give the total times when `'new_data'` and `'treatment'` are in the same row:

```
((df.group=='treatment') & (df.landing_page=='new_page')).sum()
```

Comment: Using `and` directly won't work, since `the truth value of a Series is ambiguous`. Maybe `np.logical_and`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
sum(df.group == 'treatment' & df.landing_page == 'new_page')
```

Here each of `df.group == 'treatment'`, `df.landing_page == 'new_page'` are logical arrays indicating the positions at which each predicate is `True`. The `&` operator combines them into a logical array indicating the positions at which both predicates are `True`. `sum`ming the array returns the number of `True` values.

If you want to be more verbose, this

```py
import numpy as np

sum(np.logical_and(df.group == 'treatment', df.landing_page == 'new_page'))
```

also works.

---

Although the first approach is more readable, it iterates through the whole length of the array to create the necessary temporaries. A direct "lazy" way would be

```py
sum(filter(lambda x: x['group'] == 'treatment' and x['landing_page'] == 'new_page', df.iterrows()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us stack with `pandas`

```
df['cnt']=(df.group.eq('treatment')&df.landing_page.eq('new_page')).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fact True is treated as 1 in pandas sum() function:

```py
(df.newpage!=df.treatment).sum()
```